# Using default VirtualHost without www. on domain

Tags: linux, debian, dns, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I using Debian 8.1 64-bit with a hostname set, so my login is `root@example.com`. I installed Apache2, PHP etc… and I setup a VirtualHost as well:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

DNS settings:

```
example.com     1800    A       111.111.111.111
example.com     1800    MX  1   example.com
*.example.com   1800    CNAME   example.com
```

When I go to `http://example.com/`, it loads `/var/www/html/` index, when I go `http://www.example.com/` its works great. I tried so much edits, but nothing work. Could this be connected to my server’s hostname? Any idea?

Comment: try this http://imgur.com/2VdrimM (obviously change to match with your paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you have `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` setup:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

But I would suggest setting the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` like this:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www example.* www.example.*
```

I like to use a wildcard for cases where I have multiple top level domains set for a common domain I own. But if you only have the `.com` version you could just set it like this:

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www example.com www.example.com
```

Then restart Apache and all should be good:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But if you believe this is a hostname issue, you can do this to confirm or change the server’s hostname. First, get the hostname like this:

```
hostname
```

And if you want to change that hostname, just run this command:

```
sudo hostname example.com
```

Also, check the `sysctl` setting for `kernel.hostname` like this:

```
sysctl kernel.hostname
```

And if that needs to be changed, do it like this:

```
sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=example.com
```

After that is done, make sure any settings connected to your hostname are adjusted in `/etc/hosts` if they need to be adjusted and then reboot the machine. When it comes up again, try it out and see what happens. Should be fine now.

Comment: Not helped. Maybe i bad writed a question. When i going to example.com without www. , its load a default index from /var/www/html/, but when i going to www.example.com , its load /var/www/example.com/, and i want to load still from /var/www/example.com

Comment: I think its can be something with HOSTNAME on Linux.